# qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.12.1.run - gives segmentation fault

Tags: qt, offline, segmentation-fault

My OS - Ubuntu 16.04. I have downloaded qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.12.1.run. I run it from terminal. It is giving segmentation fault.

Comment: Try running it with -v option to see what is going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by installing another version qt offline installer. In my case it is qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.9.7.run

If anyone has such problem I would suggest running any other possible version